# How to translate this "R" formula into MySQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, r, statistics

R is used for statistical computing. I don't know statistics never worked with R. I was given this formula in "R" to solve a problem, but need help to translate it into either MySQL or PHP. Below is a direct quote:

In R we can compute

```
x <- matrix(c(-954234, 3589, 43243455, 2521, 149940475, 3939,     243853640, 3936, 262995399, 3025, 751195421, 5333, 10677437299, 7477), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE); y     <- apply(x, 2, sum); y[1] / y[2],
```

producing $406,697 for the average.

Some background information on this. This is data from the IRS 2008 for Income Tax data by zip code. The above data is from a single zip code (10021). The table (please see below). The task is to create an **Average** Adjust Gross Income (AGI), and the above R example is the solution. Thanks!

```
1 = 'Under $10,000' 
2 = '$10,000 under $25,000' 
3 = '$25,000 under $50,000' 
4 = '$50,000 under $75,000' 
5 = '$75,000 under $100,000' 
6 = '$100,000 under $200,000' 
7 = '$200,000 or more '
```

"Number of Returns" is the Number of tax returns for that agi_class.

```
mysql> select A00100,zipcode,agi_class,N1 as 'Number of Returns' from taxbyzip2008 where zipcode="10021";

+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+ 
| A00100      | zipcode | agi_class | Number of Returns | 
+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+ 
| -954234     | 10021   | 1         | 3589              | 
| 43243455    | 10021   | 2         | 2521              | 
| 149940475   | 10021   | 3         | 3939              | 
| 243853640   | 10021   | 4         | 3936              | 
| 262995399   | 10021   | 5         | 3025              | 
| 751195421   | 10021   | 6         | 5333              | 
| 10677437299 | 10021   | 7         | 7477              | 
+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
select sum(A00100)/sum(N1) as 'average' from taxbyzip2008 where zipcode="10021";
```

OR quick try:

```
mysql> select (-954234 + 43243455 +149940475 + 243853640 + 262995399 + 751195421+10677437299)/(3589+2521 +3939 +3936 +3025  + 5333 + 7477) ;
```

your formula is sum of  A00100 divide by sum of N1 field :)